# Java: How to check if an object is an instance of a non-static inner class, regardless of the outer object?

Tags: java, inner-classes, instanceof

If I have an inner class e.g.

```
class Outer{
    class Inner{}
}
```

Is there any way to check if an arbitrary `Object` is an instance of any `Inner`, regardless of its outer object? `instanceof` gives false when the objects are not `Inner`s from the same `Outer`. I know a workaround is just to make `Inner` a static class, but I'm wondering if what I'm asking is possible.

Example:

```
class Outer{
    Inner inner = new Inner();
    class Inner{}

    public boolean isInner(Object o){
        return o instanceof Inner;
    }
}
```

```
Outer outer1 = new Outer();
Outer outer2 = new Outer();
boolean answer = outer1.isInner(outer2.inner); //gives false
```

Comment: Can you provide an example where `instanceof Inner` returns false?

Comment: @cambecc, `o instanceof Outer.Inner` gives false when `o` is an instance of an `Inner` of any `Outer` other than the one you're calling it from.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "any `Outer` other than the one you're calling from". A quick code example would be really useful for answering your question. You don't mean `Outer.Inner` and `OtherOuter.Inner` should be the same `Inner`, do you?

Comment: @cambecc, example included.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Just tried running it; result is `true`. Are you sure you see `false`? A result of `false` would violate JLS §15.20.2, which says: _"At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException."_ We know `outer2.inner` can be cast to `Inner` because that is its type. Try changing the argument of `isInner` to type `Inner` and you will see no explicit cast is required and no compile error occurs. Not sure why you see `false`.

Comment: Here's another use case - I want to hold a long-lived instance of a class (e.g. a `Runnable`) provided by a user calling my API but I want to ensure they're not accidentally preventing a surrounding instance from being GC'ed by passing in an anonymous/inner class. Long-lived anonymous classes can be a subtle source of memory leaks, and this check can help prevent them.

Answer (score 21):

And what about?

```
public static boolean isInnerClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isMemberClass() && !Modifier.isStatic(clazz.getModifiers());
}
```

The method [`isMemberClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isMemberClass--) will test if the method is a member (and not an anonymous or local class) and the second condition will verify that your member class is not static.

By the way, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) explains the differences between local, anonymous and nested classes.

> Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are **called inner classes**.

Comment: Just to note, `isMemberClass()` returns false for anonymous and local classes (which makes sense, but might be surprising). Use [`isAnonymousClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnonymousClass--) and [`isLocalClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isLocalClass--) if you're interested in these class types.

Answer (score 4):

> `o instanceof Outer.Inner` gives `false` when `o` is an instance of an `Inner` of any `Outer` other than the one you're calling it from.

This doesn't happen for me - I get `true` for `o instanceof Inner` regardless of which particular enclosing instance of `Outer` the `o` belongs to:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {}

  void test() {
    // Inner instance that belongs to this Outer
    Inner thisInner = new Inner();

    // Inner instance that belongs to a different Outer
    Outer other = new Outer();
    Inner otherInner = other.new Inner();

    // both print true
    System.out.println(thisInner instanceof Inner);
    System.out.println(otherInner instanceof Inner);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Outer().test();
  }
}
```

Tested with both Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

you could always:

```
getClass().getName()
```

and do a String comparison.

**EDIT** : to account for inheritance (among inner classes? who would do that?!) you could always loop through `getSuperclass()` and check for them as well, and even go after implemented interfaces.

Comment: @IanRoberts - why not? 2 Inner instances will have the same fully qualified class name, regardless of the parent object

Comment: Yes, but if `Inner2 extends Inner` then objects whose class is `Inner2` _are_ instances of `Inner` even though their class name is different.

Comment: @IanRoberts - right you are. still fixable though :-) (edit incoming)

Comment: The name of a class doesn't reveal whether its static or not.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using [getEnclosingClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass()):

> Returns the immediately enclosing class of the underlying class. **If the underlying class is a top level class this method returns null.**

```
Outer.class.equals(object.getClass().getEnclosingClass())
```

Getting the correct enclosing class of the object , IMHO is not so easy . Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/763617/1163607).

Somewhat of a hack would be :

```
object.getClass().getName().contains("Outer$");
```

Comment: but that would also work for any hypothetical OtherInner ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for finding out better answers, to find out that there are none out there.

Here is what I have which works pretty well:

```
    public static boolean isStatic(Class klass) {
            return Modifier.isStatic(klass.getModifiers());
    }

    /**
     * Non static inner class
     */
    public static boolean isInnerclass(Class klass) {
            return klass.getDeclaringClass() != null && !isStatic(klass);
    }
```

Will return true for local inner classes. isMemberClass and others do not work for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass()` method returns the immediately enclosing class of the underlying class. If this class is a top level class this method returns null.

The following example shows the usage of java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass() method:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class ClassDemo {
   // constructor
   public ClassDemo() {

      // class Outer as inner class for class ClassDemo
      class Outer {

         public void show() {
            // inner class of Class Outer
            class Inner {

               public void show() {
                  System.out.print(getClass().getName() + " inner in...");
                  System.out.println(getClass().getEnclosingClass());    
               }
            }
            System.out.print(getClass().getName() + " inner in...");
            System.out.println(getClass().getEnclosingClass());

            // inner class show() function
            Inner i = new Inner();
            i.show();
         }
      }

      // outer class show() function
      Outer o = new Outer();
      o.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     ClassDemo cls = new ClassDemo();
   }
}
```

#### Output

> ClassDemo$1Outer inner in...class ClassDemo
>
> ClassDemo$1Outer$1Inner inner in...class ClassDemo$1Outer