# May I query lambda function lifetime at runtime?

Tags: java, lambda

I know the Java compiler generates different classes for lambda functions depending on the context and closure they have. When I receive the lambda as a parameter (using the `Consumer<>` class), may I know the lifetime of the parameter?

For example, I have the following `Observable` class, that keeps a weak reference to its observes.

```java
class Observable {
    private final List<WeakReference<Consumer<Object>>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
    private Object obj;

    public Observable(Object obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void observe(Consumer<Object> cons){
        this.observables.add(new WeakReference<>(cons));
    }

    public void set(Object obj){
        this.obj = obj;
        // notify observes
        for(WeakReference<Consumer<Object>> cons : this.observables){
            if(cons.get() != null)
                cons.get().accept(this.obj);
            // clearing the non-existing observes from the list is ommited for simplicity
        }
    }
}
```

Now I use it as follows.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object c = new Object();
        Observable obs = new Observable(c);

        new ContainingClass(obs);
        obs.set(c);
        System.gc();
        obs.set(c);
    }
}
```

The code just creates the object and its observer and creates `ContainingClass` (definition follows) that observes. Then the object is set once, garbage collector explicitly called (so the created ContainingClass is deleted) and set the object a second time.

Now, as long as the lambda is instance-specific (reference either this or its instances method) it's called only once (because it is destroyed by the GC).

```java
public class ContainingClass {
    public ContainingClass(Observable obs){
        obs.observe(this::myMethod);
    }

    private void myMethod(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Hello here");
    }
}
```

```java
public class ContainingClass {
    private Object obj;

    public ContainingClass(Observable obs){
        obs.observe(obj -> {
            this.obj = obj;
            System.out.println("Hello here");
        });
    }
}
```

But as the lambda becomes static, it is called twice, even after GC.

```java
public class ContainingClass {
    public ContainingClass(Observable obs){
        obs.observe((obj) -> System.out.println("Hello here"));
    }
}
```

The reference to this lambda is never destroyed and therefore add as an observer every time `ContainingClass` instance is created. As a result, it will be stuck in observers until the program ends.

Is there a way to detect this and at least show a warning, that the lambda will be never removed?

One thing I figured out is that lambda with instance lifetime has `arg$1` property, so I can ask about the number of properties.

```java
public void observe(Consumer<Object> cons){
    if(cons.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length == 0)
        System.out.println("It is static lifetime lambda");
    this.observables.add(new WeakReference<>(cons));
}
```

Is it a universal approach? May there be a situation when this doesn't work?

Comment: *"Is it a universal approach?"* You shouldn't make any assumptions about the internal workings.

Comment: To solve your issue, I would add a mechanism to unregister an observer. When you're done with an observer, unregister it. You won't even need weak references anymore.

Comment: @Olivier I am aware of that option. In fact, I may return kind of handler that can be used to unregister callback. I may even store weak reference to this callback inside the `Observable` and as soon as its destroyed I may automatically unregister the callback itself. However, this require handling of the handler at the called side and I was looking for a more elegant solution.
I am aware I can't depend on the private properties of the callback, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: You should not depend on gc  by weakreference. you can not know if the consumer is used by  other class.

Comment: "Garbage collector is explicitly called, so the object is deleted" not quite, `System#gc` provides a _hint_ to the JVM that a garbage collection pass may be performed, but it's just as welcome to do absolutely nothing at all. In terms of reference types that could be useful here, check out `PhantomReference`, the spookiest of all the reference types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution would be the one hinted by @Olivier: you can return an object with a `remove` method that removes your `Consumer` from your list when called, like the following example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Registration {
    void remove();
}
```

```
class Observable {
    private final List<Consumer<Object>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
    private Object obj;

    public Observable(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Registration observe(Consumer<Object> cons) {
        this.observables.add(cons);
        return () -> this.observables.remove(cons);
    }

    public void set(Object obj) {
       [...]
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to check if the class the lambda belongs to is static or not, as suggested by @kutschkem, but I don't like resorting to introspection if there is a good alternative.

As already stated by @shalk, relying on `WeakReference` to handle GC can lead to unwanted behaviours, because there is no way to ensure that your `Consumer` isn't referenced (maybe by mistake) somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468198/java-how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-non-static-inner-class-rega), so the answers there apply here too.

A static nested class has a flag that can be checked:

```
 Modifier.isStatic(clazz.getModifiers())   // returns true if a class is static, false if not
```

Comment: _Your question is similar to this question, so the answers there apply here too._ Doesn't that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: @Abra The question is slightly different but contains all the necessary information. I can't bring myself to actually cast the vote, feel free to check and see if it's similar enough to be a duplicate.