# Juggling JobThreads and GUIWorkspaces in a NetLogo extension

Tags: java, multithreading, api, netlogo

I'm working on an extension that opens multiple models simultaneously. Models can be opened and closed dynamically. Models are opened as a `LiteWorkspace` so that widgets and such are displayed. Whenever you create a new `LiteWorkspace`, it starts up a `JobThread` and `Lifeguard`. The problem is that shutting down a `GUIWorkspace` (the parent class of `LiteWorkspace`) doesn't kill its `Lifeguard` or `JobThread`.

Possible solutions:

1. The ideal solution would be a to have all models share a `JobThread`, as this would remove number of threads as a cap on how many models one can run. Doing this would have certain performance benefits as well. Is there a chance this is a possible? This solution still require being able to kill `Lifeguard`.
2. Next would be to be able to kill the threads of course.
3. As a last resort, we could keep around a pool of `GUIWorkspace`s. When the user closes a model, it's thrown back into the pool. Then, when the user loads a new model and there's something in the pool, we just reuse one of those `GUIWorkspace`s. This would allow us to open the same number of models as with 2. The only downside is that opening a new model (like completely new, from the file menu or whatever) still doesn't kill the threads, so there's this permanent resource baggage hanging around. We actually might have to institute a pool anyway for performance reasons, but it would be really nice to actually be able to free up the resources at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 isn't workable; the assumption of one JobThread per Workspace is deeply embedded in the code.

To get the JobThread to die, this should be sufficient:

```
workspace.jobManager.haltPrimary()
workspace.jobManager.die()
```

To get the GUIWorkspace.Lifeguard thread to die, we just need to call `interrupt()` on it, but even just getting a reference to it isn't so easy. Here's a transcript showing a successful attempt:

```
/Applications/NetLogo 5.0.5 % scala29 -Yrepl-sync -classpath NetLogo.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).

scala> val applet = new org.nlogo.lite.Applet
applet: org.nlogo.lite.Applet = ...

scala> applet.init()
...

scala> val ws = applet.panel.workspace: org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace
ws: org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace = org.nlogo.lite.LiteWorkspace@69cafecd

scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet.asScala.foreach(println)
Thread[JobThread,4,main]
Thread[Lifeguard,6,main]
...

scala> ws.jobManager.haltPrimary()

scala> ws.jobManager.die()

scala> import util.Try
import util.Try

scala> for {
         thread <- Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet.asScala
         if thread.getName == "Lifeguard"
         outer = Try{ val field = thread.getClass.getDeclaredField("this$0")
                      field.setAccessible(true)
                      field.get(thread) }
         if outer.toOption == Some(ws)
       } {
         thread.interrupt()
         thread.join()
       }
Success(org.nlogo.lite.LiteWorkspace@69cafecd)

scala> Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet.asScala.foreach(println)
...
```

(Note that I've answered in Scala; conversion to Java left to the reader. The reflection stuff for accessing the outer instance of an inner class comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/763617/86485.)

A pull request that adds code implementing `GUIWorkspace.dispose()` in a cleaner way would be welcome.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks! The `this$0` was pretty clever.